# JScrollpane scroll bars are not showing up

Tags: java

I cant seem to get the scroll bars to show up. I notice that there is a small box down at the bottom of my application when i have the scroll pane code added in, but its too small to do anything with and it definately is not making the text area i need scrollable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
mainFrame = new JFrame();       
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    messageArea = new JTextArea(20, 35);
    messageEntry = new JTextArea(5, 35);
    fl = new FlowLayout();
    currentMessage = "";

    sp = new JScrollPane(messageArea);
    sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    sp.setSize(100, 100);

    messageArea.setEditable(false);
    messageArea.setLineWrap(true);


    menuBar.add(menu);

    sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(this);
    mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,500));
    mainFrame.setLayout(fl);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.blue);
    mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    mainFrame.add(messageArea);
    mainFrame.add(messageEntry);
    mainFrame.add(sp);
    mainFrame.add(sendButton);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setTitle("Communicator");
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding `messageArea` directly to `mainFrame` later in the code, which is plucking it out of the scroll pane, leaving the scroll pane empty. Remove the `mainFrame.add(messageArea);` line. You only need to add the scroll pane itself to the window.

Comment: Wow i have been fighting with that for an hour. Thanks!